# AJAX - Dynamic data out of a href for query

Tags: php, ajax

I have a page full of favorite buttons, that until know (after a click) went to an external page and then reloaded the page (via queries in the url). But now I want that the same action is send via AJAX and therefore no page reload is needed.

```
    ?page=index&action=favorite&hash=IDFROMTHEFAV

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" id="1" name="favorite>FAV 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="2" name="favorite>FAV 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="3" name="favorite>FAV 3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Can somebody help me in this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can change them to buttons, and onClick call functiun that do all the AJAX stuff, but if you want to use <a> you should call functions this way -> onclick="yourFunc(); return false". Or you can prevent default action of <a> tag in yourFunc body.

Comment: This is very broad question that will probably require a back and forth dialog rather than a one-off question and answer. I'd suggest doing some primarily reading and taking a stab this yourself. If/when you run into problems, we can help steer you in the right direction - but there isn't enough question here that can be answered right now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this in your `index.php`

```
function getXMLHttpRequest() {
    var ajax = false;

    if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if ( window.ActiveXObject ) {
        try {
            ajax = new ActiveXObject( "Msxml2.XMLHTTP" );
        } catch ( e ) {
            try {
                ajax = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
            } catch ( e ) {}
        }
    }

    return ajax;
}

document.getElementById('link1').onload = function(e) {
    var ajax = getXMLHttpRequest();

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        'use strict';
        if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
            if (ajax.status === 200 || ajax.status === 304) {
                var data = ajax.responseText;
                console.log( data );
                // document.body.innerHTML = data;
            }
        }
    };

    ajax.open('GET', 'test.json', true);
    ajax.send(null);

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
};
```

You could also create a php script that either returns XML or JSON and then you format for display in your html